# Best practices for finding lay academic reading communities in your local church?

Tags: doubt

A n00b here with my first question. I've long struggled to find lay reading communities within the local church who are interested in reading books that are more academic in nature or journal articles. Here are just some current examples of books or topics that I would like to process with others: Metzger's Canon of the NT, many of NT Wright's academic work, 5 views on biblical inerrancy (Counterpoints series), patristic fathers on Gen. 1. My reformed/covenantal perspective suggests that I should not read alone, but my experience has been that I've repeatedly knocked and sought over the years, and the most common reactions I receive are well-intentioned folks who think that I should: (1) stop asking questions, (2) think these topics uninteresting, or (3) that I am a heretic (implicitly). If you've succeeded in forming a local reading community, could you please share your secret? It's not that I don't appreciate this wonderful forum or other digital media, it's just that, for me, I really long for an in person community, COVID notwithstanding.

Comment: How big is your church? While you could probably start a reading group in most churches, those are some pretty niche topics, so it's not surprising you haven't had much interest. You might want to start with something more accessible, like a Tim Keller book. And if you start such a group you'll have to be prepared to read the suggested books of others even if they don't interest you as much.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My church is actually pretty big, ~1k. And it's an EPC church. But I don't think most members even know that we are reformed and EPC. Keller is a great suggestion. I am certainly open to other topics, but I am hoping that we tackle deeper subjects and in a more rigorous fashion. I am involved in small groups, so I am connected, but I just don't have an academic reading community.